# Why does my jQuery delegated click fire multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, delegation

I am copying an element and adding it to a a list of elements. First, I get some HTML using an ajax call:

```
var setButtonClick = function (url, btn) {
    $.ajax(url, $('form').serialize(), 'Html').then(function (data) {
        $(btn).parent().find(sel.addListItem).on('click', function () {
            addListItem(data, this, btn);              
        });

        addListItem(data, btn, btn);          
    });
}
```

`addListItem` looks like this:

```
var addListItem = function (data, context, btn) {
    
    var $template = $(data);
    // stuff not related removed for brevity
          
    $(btn).before($template);      
}
```

I then have a remove function using a delegate:

```
 $(sel.editableList).delegate(sel.removeListItem, 'click', function () {
     // fires once for every element with the sel.removeListItem selector
 }
```

I need the click event to fire once for the clicked element only.  I can get a basic version of `delegate` working by inserting content like this:

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "p", "click", function() {
    $( this ).after( "<p>Another paragraph!</p>" );
});
```

Therefore, I'm thinking it may be because I'm inserting a copy of the element or is it the same element I'm adding over and over?  I've also tried to use `clone` to create a new element before inserting like:

```
 var $template = $(data).clone();
```

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong with this please?

Comment: This is because you are binding click event multiple time after every ajax response here `$(btn).parent().find(sel.addListItem).on('click', function () {`

Comment: thanks, are you sure? The problem buttons are sel.removeListItem, not addListItem

Comment: fyi, `delegate()` is deprecated in favor of `on()` with an extra selector as the second argument

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I have changed this thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every time your ajax is called you attach a click event handler to the elements. It gets called repeatedly, because you add it to the elements that already existed and had this handler attached.

The solution for your problem is to detach previously attached handlers with `off()` function.

```
var setButtonClick = function (url, btn) {
    $.ajax(url, $('form').serialize(), 'Html').then(function (data) {
        $(btn).parent().find(sel.addListItem)
            .off('click')
            .on('click', function () {
                addListItem(data, this, btn);              
            });

        addListItem(data, btn, btn);          
    });
}
```

## #

In the future you may want to attach different click event handlers or may want to turn off specific handlers, for that you could use namespaces.

```
$(elem).on('event.namespace', function(){});
$(elem).off('event.namespace');
```

That way you could have multiple click event handlers on one element. This would be the code if you have more than one click event handlers

```
var setButtonClick = function (url, btn) {
    $.ajax(url, $('form').serialize(), 'Html').then(function (data) {
        $(btn).parent().find(sel.addListItem)
            .off('click.addItem')
            .on('click.addItem', function () {
                addListItem(data, this, btn);              
            });

        addListItem(data, btn, btn);          
    });
}
```

## #

And here's the example.

```js
$('.btn').on('click.ns1', function(){
  alert('Hey');
});

$('.btn').on('click.ns2', function(){
  alert('How you doin?');
});


// Comment me out to see the difference
$('.btn').off('click.ns2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks, I will look at this carefully.  Why is the way I'm attaching 'addListItem' causing multiple clicks from 'removeListItem'?  'addListItem' is working as it should.

Comment: You should check where in your code something gets binded and then you should unbind before binding all elements again. If you only attach the event handler to a created element, then detaching is not necessary.